# Noisy sound in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio

I dual booted Ubuntu 22.04 in my Lenovo windows laptop. In windows my speakers produce clear sound and loud.

But in Ubuntu sound was low so I turned on volume amplification and adjusted the volume to 150%, and now sound is noisy and not clear. How can I solve the issue.

Comment: You probably can't solve it. In Windows it works with a very customized version of the chipset's manufacturer driver.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Then I have to use linux with this issue